# Django model is saving twice

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save Authors model, but it keeps saving twice into the database.
views.py

```
........................
            for book_data in data['items']:
                volume_info = book_data['volumeInfo']
                title = volume_info['title']
                genres = volume_info.get('categories')
                authors = volume_info.get('authors')
                description = volume_info.get('description')
                if not Books.objects.filter(title=title).exists():
                    book = Books.objects.create(title=title, description=description)

                    # Does authors exists in database?
                    existing_authors = Authors.objects.filter(author_name__in=authors)
                    existing_authors_names = {authors.author_name for authors in existing_authors}

                    # Create a list of missing authors
                    missing_authors = [
                        Authors(author_name=author_name)
                        for author_name in authors
                        if author_name not in existing_authors_names
                    ]
                    # Creating author before adding it to relation
                    if missing_authors:
                        missing_authors = Authors.objects.bulk_create(missing_authors)
                        print(missing_authors)
                        for m in missing_authors:
                            m.save()

                    # Adding to relation
                    book.authors.add(*existing_authors, *missing_authors)
..........................
```

I think the problem is in for m in missing_authors right?

models.py

```
class Authors(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.author_name


class Books(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Authors, blank=True)
    genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genres, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

database is sqllite3
Django version is 2.2.1

Comment: Maybe it'd help if you provide your environment: your Models, database type, and Django version. There're some caveats when using `bulk_create`, as you can see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create). It seems `bulk_create` is writing once and when you call `m.save()` you're doing it again.

Comment: added the models and rest

Answer (score 1):

The [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) method automatically saves the results after the query is executed.

Change your code to this:

```
if missing_authors:
    Authors.objects.bulk_create(missing_authors)


''' remove these lines
    for m in missing_authors:
        m.save()

#not sure what this line is doing exactly, but it might be causing your problem
book.authors.add(*existing_authors, *missing_authors)
'''
```

### Update

If you can set `unique=True` for your author_name column, then try the following:

```
class Authors(models.Model):
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
```

```
Authors.objects.bulk_create(missing_authors, ignore_conflicts=True)
for m in missing_authors:
    m.save()

book.authors.add(*existing_authors, *missing_authors)
```

Comment: book.authors.add is adding the created Author model to M2M relationship. When i delete the for loop its raises that error "Cannot add "<Authors: John Ronald Reuel Tolkien>": instance is on database "default", value is on database "None""

Comment: Can you try removing the `book.authors.add` line? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837033/valueerror-cannot-add-instance-is-on-database-default-value-is-on-databas/7999014) question explains that error.

Comment: Also, can you update your question with your models?  There are other workarounds I can think of if you **have to** keep the `book.authors.add` line.

Comment: When i remove it it saves great but then Books model doesnt have an authors. Also added the models.

Comment: Updated the Model now it says: UNIQUE constraint failed: api_authors.author_name

Comment: Did u figured out something?